# Vue.js Push doesn't update view

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I create a array which contains objects describing information of buttons. In my template I have a class `active` which is represent the active button. By default the first button of the array is active.

template:

```
<b-button-group class="page-buttons mt-2" size="sm">
   <b-button v-for="btn in buttons" 
      :key="btn.key" 
      @click="selectPage(btn.key)"
      v-bind:class="{'active': btn.active}">{{ btn.caption }}
   </b-button>
 </b-button-group>
```

Script:

```
methods: {
    $createPaginationButtons: function(numberParameters) {
      const numberPages = Math.ceil(numberParameters / NUMBER_ELEMENT_PER_PAGE);
      this.buttons = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < numberPages; i++) {
        this.buttons.push({
          caption: `PAGE ${i + 1}`,
          active: (i === 0),
          key: (i + 1)
        });
      }

      Vue.set(this.buttons[0], 'active', true);
   }
}
```

The buttons array is initialize in data as an empty array.
when my buttons array changes, the view is updated and display the correct number of buttons but my class `active` is not triggered.

Have you any idea.

Comment: Can you please share the `data` object?, also when or what triggers `createPaginationButtons`?

Answer (score 1):

Push is a wrapped method so it will trigger a view update.

Do you have declared buttons on the data property?

```
data() {
     buttons:[]
}
```

Since you are creating the active property as i === 0 you don't need Vue.set.

I don't know if has something to do but instead of making buttons empty and then pushing,  use an aux variable to create the array and then just do this.buttons = auxVariable. This should trigger an update.

Comment: Yes i have declared `buttons` in data property like your code. I don't understand what is aux variables ?

Comment: I mean to push the array into a different variable, a local variable of the function, and then just assing the value of this new variable to the buttons variable.

Comment: I try this option too, but it's the same result, it doesn't update my view :/

Comment: Mmm, have you checked if the array contains something? It is weird. Maybe the loop is not iterating and then the view doesn't update because the array is empty.

Comment: No everything is correct, i don't understand why too. My arrays contains the correct values, the view is updated and dispay the correct number of buttons but my class `active` is not triggered

Comment: When you inspect the element on the browser the active class is not there? Try removing the v-bind and adding the class to see if it's a css issue.

Comment: It's weird when I put active in class and removing v-bind, when the component is mounted the active class is there, but when the watch is triggered and buttons change the class is not there

Comment: Ok I find a solution, if I rename my class `active` by any other word it works. I have no idea why

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but I'm out of ideas. The last thing I can say is show on the template {{btn.active}} and see if it shows as true. I tried something like that myself and there's no issue, if btn.active is true the class should be added.

Comment: Oh, I was writing and didn't realise you replied, really weird.